# Creating individual dataframes from a grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that needs to be split into individual files based on the value of a variable in the dataframe. There are scores of individuals and confidential information in the dataframe, thus a simplified example is below. I want the split to be based on the variable "first".

```
first <-  c("Jon", "Bill", "Bill" , "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
age <- c(23, 41, 41 , 32, 58, 26)

df <- data.frame(first , age)
df
```

For example, I want the file with Jon to have one line and the file with Bill to have two lines. I've attempted the following but I'm stuck. I don't know how to get individual dataframes from the list df.split.

```
library(tidyverse)
df.grped <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(first)

df.split <- 
  group_split(df.grped)
```

So I would like to have the files:
df.split_Jon, df.split_Bill, df.split_Maria, etc. The actual source file is large so I don't want to specify each.

Since I understand working in tidyverse the best I'd like to have the solution there, if possible. Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After splitting the data set by the unique values of the first column, we make use of `list2env` function to create a separated `dataframe` of each subset into the global environment as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

setNames(df %>% 
           group_split(first), paste0("df.split_", unique(df$first))) %>%
  list2env(envir = globalenv())
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem concisely! setNames is new to me so I'll look at that more.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a very useful function for naming any R object. Any object like a vector, dataframe and list where `names` attribute is meaningful. The second argument is `nm` which is a character vector you use to name your data structure. `purrr::set_names` is the `tidyverse` equivalent which does the same.

Comment: Might be just me, but `df %>% group_split(first)` is rather confusing, I'd go for `group_split(df, first)`.

Comment: @Maël Believe me I thought about it since it is used inside another function and the code chunk is not that big, I also think there is no need to use the pipe operator inside `setNamse`. Thank you for mentioning anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_split(first) %>%
  walk(~ assign(str_c("df.split_", .[1, 1]), value = ., envir = .GlobalEnv))

names(.GlobalEnv)
#> [1] "df.split_Bill"  "first"          "df.split_Maria" "df.split_Ben"  
#> [5] "df.split_Tina"  "age"            "df.split_Jon"   "df"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using {purrr} and {rlang}. We first split the `data.frame` with `dplyr::group_split`, then name it with `purrr::set_names` and `map_chr`, and then assign it with `rlang::env_bind` in which we can splice it using `!!!`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_split(first) %>% 
  set_names(map_chr(., ~ paste0("df_", .$first[[1]]))) %>% 
  rlang::env_bind(.GlobalEnv, !!! .)

ls()
#> [1] "age"      "df"       "df_Ben"   "df_Bill"  "df_Jon"   "df_Maria" "df_Tina" 
#> [8] "first"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Further note: I thought I would add this in case someone ran into the problem I found. I used solution 1 on the real dataset and found that the dataset had to be sorted by the argument in the unique function ("first" in the example) in order for it to work. (I realize it did not need to be sorted in the example.)  Names appeared to be assigned in the sort order of this variable, and if it was not sorted then the names did not correspond to the correct variable.